# Plot a zoom of the plot inside the same plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to resolve the following issues:

I have two plots p1 and p2 and now I want to join the two graphs with a dotted line. Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLB0.png).

This is the code for this graph

```
> p1 + 
> annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p2), xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10) +
> geom_rect(aes(xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10), color='black', linetype='dashed', alpha=0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAjdt.png)

I was trying this code:

```
> p1 + 
> annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p2), xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10) +
> geom_rect(aes(xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10), color='black', linetype='dashed', alpha=0) +
> geom_path(aes(x,y,group=grp), 
> data=data.frame(x = c(0,120,0,120), y=c(0,0,5,10),grp=c(1,1,2,2)),
> linetype='dashed')
```

but it doesn't work. I got this error:

```
> Error in `geom_path()`:
> Problem while computing aesthetics.
> Error occurred in the 6th layer.
> Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4)
> Fix the following mappings: `colour`
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My question is: how can I resolve this? Thank you in advance!

Here is the entire code:

```
> library(ggforce)
> 
> set.seed(123)
> subject <- rep(sprintf('subject%d', 1:12), 5)
> pk <- c(rep(0,12), runif(12,4.5,5.0), runif(12,3.8,4.4), runif(12,2.0,3.7), runif(12,0.1,2.0))
> time <- c(rep(0,12), rep(1,12), rep(6,12), rep(24,12), rep(14*24,12))
> time_1 <- c(rep(0,12), rep(1,12), rep(6,12), rep(24,12))
> subject_1 <- rep(sprintf('subject%d', 1:12), 4)
> pk_1 <- c(rep(0,12), runif(12,4.5,5.0), runif(12,3.8,4.4), runif(12,2.0,3.7))
> 
> 
> time_units_dataset <- "hours"
> time_units_plot    <- "days"
> 
> pk_data <- data.frame(subject, pk, time)
> pk_data_1 <- data.frame(subject_1, pk_1, time_1)
> 
> p1 <- ggplot(data = pk_data, aes(x = time, 
> y = pk,
> color = subject,
> group = subject)) +
> geom_line(size = 0.7) +
> geom_point(size=2, shape=6) +
> geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 24, ymin = 0, ymax = 5), color = 'black', alpha = 0) +
> xgx_scale_x_time_units(units_dataset = time_units_dataset, units_plot = time_units_plot,
> breaks = c(0, 1, 6, 24, 14*24),
> labels = c('Pre-dose', '1hr', '6hrs', '24hrs', 'Day 14'),
> guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 3)) +
> scale_color_manual(name = 'Subjects',
> labels = c('Subject 1 (Panel 1)', 'Subject 2 (Panel 1)', 'Subject 3 (Panel 2)', 'Subject 4 (Panel 2)',
>                                 'Subject 5 (Panel 3)', 'Subject 6 (Panel 3)', 'Subject 7 (Panel 4)', 'Subject 8 (Panel 4)',
>                                 'Subject 9 (Panel 5)', 'Subject 10 (Panel 5)', 'Subject 11 (Panel 6)', 'Subject 12 (Panel 6)'),
> values = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green",
>                                 "orange", "orange", "violet", "violet", "yellow2", "yellow2")) +
> labs(y = 'Concentration (ng/ml)') +
>   #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))
> theme_bw() +
> theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
> 
> p1 
> 
> #The plot with a zoom
> p2 <- ggplot(data = pk_data_1, aes(x = time_1, y = pk_1,
> color = subject_1,
> group = subject_1)) +
> geom_line() +
> geom_point(size=2, shape=6) +
> xgx_scale_x_time_units(units_dataset = time_units_dataset, units_plot = time_units_plot,
> breaks = c(0, 1, 6, 24),
> labels = c('Pre-dose', '1hr', '6hrs', '24hrs'),
> guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 1)) +
> scale_color_manual(name = 'Subjects',
> labels = c('Subject 1 (Panel 1)', 'Subject 2 (Panel 1)', 'Subject 3 (Panel 2)', 'Subject 4 (Panel 2)',
>                                 'Subject 5 (Panel 3)', 'Subject 6 (Panel 3)', 'Subject 7 (Panel 4)', 'Subject 8 (Panel 4)',
>                                 'Subject 9 (Panel 5)', 'Subject 10 (Panel 5)', 'Subject 11 (Panel 6)', 'Subject 12 (Panel 6)'),
> values = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green",
>                                 "orange", "orange", "violet", "violet", "yellow2", "yellow2")) +
> labs(y = 'Concentration (ng/ml)') +
> xgx_theme_set() +
> theme(legend.position = 'none',
> axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
> 
> p2
> 
> p1 + 
> annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p2), xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10) +
> geom_rect(aes(xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10), color='black', linetype='dashed', alpha=0) +
> geom_path(aes(x,y,group=grp), 
> data=data.frame(x = c(0,120,0,120), y=c(0,0,5,10),grp=c(1,1,2,2)),
> linetype='dashed')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `geom_path` inherits the global mapping from `ggplot()`, i.e. `colour=subject`. And as there is no column named `subject` in the dataset you specified for this layer it uses the vector `subject` defined in the global environment which happens to be a vector of length 60. To fix that add `inherit.aes=FALSE` to `geom_path` to not inherit the global aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 +
  annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p2),
    xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10
  ) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 120, xmax = 336, ymin = 4, ymax = 10),
    color = "black", linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0
  ) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y, group = grp),
    data = data.frame(
      x = c(0, 120, 0, 120),
      y = c(0, 0, 5, 10),
      grp = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
    ),
    linetype = "dashed", inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
```

[image]